# select is not firing any event from jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, select

I have looked for a lot and now I don't really know what to do. My problem is that I have a select control in a HTML5 document, like this:

```
<label for="efectosId" >Elija un efecto</label>
<select id="efectosId" >
  <option value="THRESHOLD" selected>Limite</option>
  <option value="GRAY">Escala de grises</option>
  <option value="OPAQUE">Opacidad</option>
  <option value="INVERT">Invertir</option>
  <option value="POSTERIZE">Posterizar</option>
  <option value="DILATE">Desenfoque Dilatar</option>
  <option value="BLUR">Desenfoque blur</option>
  <option value="ERODE">Desenfoque Erosionar</option>
</select>
```

Also, in a JavaScript file I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#efectosId").on("change",function(){
        alert("hola mundo");
    });
});
```

When I try the code in a single document where I load jQuery library, it goes fine, but when I need to use it in a document where I load jQuery library, jQuery mobile library and jQuery ui library in that order, then it doesn't work:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="./bgrins-spectrum-98454b5/spectrum.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"  integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Please, could I have any support?? This is driving me mad
Thanks!

Comment: Check your browser console ..

Comment: try like this
$(document).on('change', '#efectosId', function(){
alert('ssdas');
});

Comment: In all your `<script>` tags, you're not loading jQuery. You're loading Bootstrap, jQuery-mobile, jQuery-UI, but not jQuery.

Comment: Change all http:// to https:// - your code works just fine when you add jQuery first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, The solution is that when I add a select using the libraries of jquery mobile ,jquery ui and bootstrap, the select control change the structure of my HTML:

```
<div class="ui-selectmenu-menu ui-front ui-selectmenu-open" style="top: 105px; left: 769.5px;"><ul aria-hidden="false" aria-labelledby="efectosId-button" id="efectosId-menu" role="listbox" tabindex="0" class="ui-menu ui-corner-bottom ui-widget ui-widget-content" aria-activedescendant="ui-id-7" aria-disabled="false" style="width: 196px;"><li class="ui-menu-item"><div id="ui-id-2" tabindex="-1" role="option" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">Limite</div></li><li class="ui-menu-item"><div id="ui-id-3" tabindex="-1" role="option" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">Escala de grises</div></li><li class="ui-menu-item"><div id="ui-id-4" tabindex="-1" role="option" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">Opacidad</div></li><li class="ui-menu-item"><div id="ui-id-5" tabindex="-1" role="option" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">Invertir</div></li><li class="ui-menu-item"><div id="ui-id-6" tabindex="-1" role="option" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">Posterizar</div></li><li class="ui-menu-item"><div id="ui-id-7" tabindex="-1" role="option" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper ui-state-active">Desenfoque Dilatar</div></li><li class="ui-menu-item"><div id="ui-id-8" tabindex="-1" role="option" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">Desenfoque blur</div></li><li class="ui-menu-item"><div id="ui-id-9" tabindex="-1" role="option" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">Desenfoque Erosionar</div></li></ul></div>
```

so when I call it from jquery I have to call it like this:

```
$("#efectosId-menu").on("click",function(e){
    console.log(e.target.textContent);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I reordered the script tags and removed integrity from jquery.min.js

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#efectosId").on("change",function(){
        alert("hola mundo");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="./bgrins-spectrum-98454b5/spectrum.js"></script>

<label for="efectosId" >Elija un efecto</label>
                <select id="efectosId" >
                    <option value="THRESHOLD" selected>Limite</option>
                    <option value="GRAY">Escala de grises</option>
                    <option value="OPAQUE">Opacidad</option>
                    <option value="INVERT">Invertir</option>
                    <option value="POSTERIZE">Posterizar</option>
                    <option value="DILATE">Desenfoque Dilatar</option>
                    <option value="BLUR">Desenfoque blur</option>
                    <option value="ERODE">Desenfoque Erosionar</option>
                </select>
```

Comment: You also need to make all scripts https

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are loading bootstrap before jquery, use this order instead:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"  integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="./bgrins-spectrum-98454b5/spectrum.js"></script>
```

From bootstrap doc:

> **Plugin dependencies**
>
> Some plugins and CSS components depend on other plugins. If you
>   include plugins individually, make sure to check for these
>   dependencies in the docs. **Also note that all plugins depend on jQuery
>   (this means jQuery must be included before the plugin files)**. Consult
>   our bower.json to see which versions of jQuery are supported.

Answer (score 0):

Try to load jquery browser dependent, like if you don't need jquery mobile, just don't load it, I think they have conflicts

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
                <title>dfgasdg</title>
                <script
              src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
              integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
              crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            </head>
            <body>
              <label for="efectosId" >Elija un efecto</label>
                            <select id="efectosId" >
                                <option value="THRESHOLD" selected>Limite</option>
                                <option value="GRAY">Escala de grises</option>
                                <option value="OPAQUE">Opacidad</option>
                                <option value="INVERT">Invertir</option>
                                <option value="POSTERIZE">Posterizar</option>
                                <option value="DILATE">Desenfoque Dilatar</option>
                                <option value="BLUR">Desenfoque blur</option>
                                <option value="ERODE">Desenfoque Erosionar</option>
                            </select>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#efectosId").on("change",function(){
                    alert("hola mundo");
                });
            });
            </script>
            </body>
            </html>
```